# why multiindex sort is so slow in pandas 0.25.3

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a small program that was originally written with an old version of pandas (cannot remember the exact version). It worked fine, nothing weird in particular. Later on, I updated my pandas to the newest version, but subsequently realized that another important package I must use for my work only supports pandas<=0.25.3. So I downgraded my pandas to 0.25.3.

Then I found my small program mentioned earlier takes forever to complete. I managed to detect which line in the program slowed the performance, and it was the multiindex sort that casused trouble `df.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True`. see below how slow it is.

[image: timing the line]

So my DataFrame is a typical panel data structure with multiindex of id (from 1 to 21) and date (from 1992-01-03 to 2019-06-28 daily), the data consists of 145108 observations/rows.

Can anyone please give me a little bit guidance about why sort_index is so slow in 0.25.3, and how to get around with this? I am sure it works fine in pandas 1.0 and even the older version before 0.25.3.

Comment: What's the other package are you using ?

Comment: the other package is not involved in this program

Comment: If it works in a version prior to 0.25.3 and your requirement is <= that, then just `pip install pandas==<older version>`